# prevent certain characters from being entered in a textfield

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to only allow the following characters to be entered into a text box:

`A` through `Z` capital and lower case, `Ñ` and `ñ`, and space. Onkeyup on run the following function:

```
FieldOnKeyUp(el) { !(/^[A-zÑñ-\s]*$/i).test(el.value)?el.value
= el.value.replace(/[^A-zÑñ-\s]/ig,''):null; }
```

The bad thing with what I've done is that the field still accepts the following special characters:

```
` ^ _ \ ] and [
```

Does anyone have some wisdom on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your regular expression:

```
[^A-zÑñ-\s]/ig
    ^---- problem is here: you need to change to an uppercase Z
```

You've got the `/i` ignore case flag set, but you've also put a character range of `A-z` - i.e., capital A through to lowercase z. The extra characters currently being accepted that you don't want ("[", etc.) all fall between the uppercase Z and lowercase a. Try changing it to `A-Z` and see what happens.

Also, note that your users may enter invalid characters by pasting (via the main menu or the right-click menu) and a key event handler won't catch that.

Comment: yea, I also run it onBlur to thwart those pasters! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Change your code part to some thing like follows and see

```
FieldOnKeyUp(el) { !(/^[a-zA-ZÑñ-\s]*$/i).test(el.value)?el.value 
= el.value.replace(/[^a-zA-ZÑñ-\s]/ig,''):null; }
```

And didnt get what is your actual requirement. Putting caret `^` inside the `[` and `]` will makes the target string not to allow the alphabets. But as per your coding I just modified the incorrect regex pattern.